# `Partial<this['someProperty']>` not working in typescript

Tags: typescript

Given

```
class A {
    props: {
        bool?: boolean,
        test: string
    } = {
        test: 'a'
    };
    setProps(newProps: Partial<this['props']>) {

    }
    a() {
        this.setProps({
            bool: false
        });
    }
}
```

I get an error

> Argument of type `{ bool: false; }` is not assignable to parameter of type `Partial<this["props"]>`.(2345)

As can be viewed here: [same code in typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa7oAcBOB7TEAXIqhmdAEa64gD8xVNApmAHYA0p56ALkxD2IDsAS1YBzLugC%200ALwk03aHwHEA5GHVTo0gNw6ITHgAU8BABSsmAdzP4i0E2Gw8RYEAB4eACxEQAbXUcB3UAXQA%20AEpFHWkdMAsY5CVuX38AOiNTcwgLFOVyRhBiADMPIx0yaSiDVN1UaSA)

When the `A.props` property is defined as `{bool?: boolean, test?: string}` with `test` optional it does work, so it looks as if the `Partial<>` is just completely ignored.

Is there a way to get the `Partial` to work in conjunction with `this`.

---

The above describes the minimal case, for context: My current situation is that I have lots of classes with props that extends from a main class that has a `setProps` and I would like to type that inherited `setProps`.

```
class Parent {
    props: any;
    setProps(newProps: Partial<this['props']>) {/*...*/}
}
class A extends Parent{
    props: {
        bool?: boolean,
        test: string
    } = /* ... */;
    a() {
        this.setProps({
            bool: false
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: On first glance I'd say you could go the extra way and define an interface for it. Iam just wondering how anything not in class scope would interpret `this['props']`

Comment: @MikeS. Could you elaborate how you would propose approaching this? My current situation is that I have lots of classes with props that extends from a main class that has a 'setProps' and I would like to type that inherited setProps.

Comment: Very relevant: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41495 -- Looks like a conscious design trade-off by the TS team. Essentially, when you use `this['props']` as a type, TS assumes you mean `this` to refer to possible subclasses of `A` as well (because if you aren't, why not just use `A`?), which may override the type of `props`. So, `this['props']` is not the same type as `{ bool?: boolean, test: string }` -- it's its own "irreducible type" if you will, because a subclass' `props` may look completely different, like `{ bool: number: test: Function }`.

Comment: So when you try to use `Partial<this['props']>`, the type of `bool?` is not `boolean | undefined`, it's `this['props']['bool'] | undefined`.

Comment: @AndrewLi Thank you so much for sharing that!

Answer (score 3):

**Edit #2:** Maybe another approach is more suitable for you. The following code implements the class `Parent` as an generic one receiving the interface of the properties (here `PropsA`) of an extending class (here `A`).

```
class Parent<T> {

    props: T;

    constructor(props: T) {
        this.props = props;
    }

    setProps(props: Partial<T>) {
        Object.assign(this.props, props);
    }
}

interface PropsA {
    bool?: boolean;
    test: string;
}

class A extends Parent<PropsA> {

    constructor() {
        super({ test: 'A' });
    }

    a() {
        this.setProps({
            bool: false,
            // Yields error:
            // nonExistingProperty: true
        });
    }
}

const obj = new A();
console.log(obj.props); // { test: 'a' }

obj.setProps({ test: 'foo', bool: true });
console.log(obj.props); // { test: 'foo', bool: true }

obj.setProps({ test: 'foo' });
console.log(obj.props); // { test: 'foo', bool: true }

obj.a();
console.log(obj.props); // { test: 'foo', bool: false }

// Yields error:
// obj.setProps({ test: 'foo', nonExistingProperty: true });
```

Instead of an interface, something like `class A extends Parent<{ bool?: boolean; test: string;}> { ...` would also do the job. However I think, that an interface makes more sense here.

**Edit #1:** I have experimented a bit with [`ThisType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thistypetype). However I am not sure about its benefit, but maybe it is worth to mention:

```
type Descriptor<T, P> = ThisType<T> & Partial<P>;

class A {
    props: {
        bool?: boolean,
        test: string
    } = {
        test: 'a'
    };
    setProps<T = Descriptor<this, this['props']>>(newProps: T) {
        Object.assign(this.props, newProps);
    }
    a() {
        this.setProps({
            bool: true
        });
    }
}

const obj = new A();
console.log(obj.props); // { test: 'a' }

obj.setProps({ test: 'foo', bool: true });
console.log(obj.props); // { test: 'foo', bool: true }
```

**Original answer**: Try `Partial<A['props']>`:

```
class A {
    props: {
        bool?: boolean,
        test: string
    } = {
        test: 'a'
    };
    setProps(newProps: Partial<A['props']>) {
        // First naive assignment
        Object.assign(this.props, newProps);
    }
    a() {
        this.setProps({
            bool: false
        });
    }
}
```

I guess the error appears because of `this`.

Comment: When you have a question 'Is there a way to get the Partial to work in conjunction with this.' the answer really shouldn't be 'just hardcode it to `A`'.  Also note the 'for context' section.

Comment: When I try it it doesn't throw an error at all: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhDOBjATgSzMA9sgPAFQBooAFAPigF4o8ALVePcCfcgMhIENlhUOAbHGQDcAWABQ4xHw7x4UAIJQA3uKhqoYZJjDwAXMtXqjAI0yY+Afn2nzEDgDsCho2uAJg++MDT2A5s6gAX0oDMRd1Ny99AHIOaIDA0TD1eAhgYi0dfBC4JDQMbBxgOngiYvoAbWjNbXhogF1SUgAKewgAdwza-TwASlDwtQB5YwArCERgADoZeFRfe2by+CmanSI2zsz4XqSjQICOZv6VZPDlqdT07ebTwZd7THsAUQAPeh4-LshuEBjI4DxM4uQK7BLiA5iIA

Comment: You are welcome :) Do you want to get an error message while doing something like `this.setProps({ nonExistingProperty: 'test' });`?

Comment: That's what I would consider the point of typing a function, otherwise I can just leave it as `newProps: any` (which I have currently) :)

Comment: Awarded the bounty, using generics like that seems to do the trick. Andrew Li in the comments touched upon an issue explaining what's happening under the hood.

Comment: Glad I could help a bit. The issue added by @AndrewLi is indeed interesting.